# pyspark dataframe foreach to fill a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, foreach, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working in Spark 1.6.1 and Python 2.7 and I have this thing to solve:

- Get a dataframe A with X rows
- For each row in A, depending on a field, create one or more rows of a new dataframe B
- Save that new dataframe B

The solution that I've come up right now, is to collect dataframe A, go over it, append to a list the row(s) of B and then create the dataframe B from that list.

With this solution i obviously lose all the perks of working with dataframes and I would like to use **foreach**, but I can't find a way to make this work. I've tried this so far:

- Pass an empty list to the foreach function (this just ignores the foreach function and doesn't do anything)
- Create a global variable to be use in the foreach function (complains that it can't find the list)

Does anyone has any ideas?

Thank you

----------------------EDIT:

Examples of the things I've tried:

```
def f(row, list):
    if row.one:
        list += [Row(type='one', field='ok')]
    else:
        list += [Row(type='one', field='ok')]
        list += [Row(type='two', field='nok')]

list = []
dfA.foreach(lambda x : f(x, list))
```

As I mention, this does nothing, it doesn't execute the function

And I've also tried (which list defined at the beginning of the class):

```
global list
def f(row):
    if row.one:
        list += [Row(type='one', field='ok')]
    else:
        list += [Row(type='one', field='ok')]
        list += [Row(type='two', field='nok')]

dfA.foreach(list)
```

---------EDIT 2:

What I'm doing right now is:

```
    list = []
    for row in dfA.collect():
        string = re.search(a_regex, row['raw'])
        if string:
            dates = re.findall(date_regex, string.group())
            for date in dates:
                date_string = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                list += [Row(event_type='1', event_date=date_string)]

        b_string = re.search(b_regex, row['raw'])
        if b_string:
            dates = re.findall(date_regex, b_string.group())
            for date in dates:
                scheduled_to = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                list += [Row(event_type='2', event_date= date_string)]
```

and then:

```
dfB = self._sql_context.createDataFrame(list)
```

dfA is given by other process, I can't change it and i know it's a very stupid way of using dataframes but I can't do anything about that

--------------------EDIT3:
dfA.raw sample:

```
{"new":[],"removed":[{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16","scheduled_by_system":null}]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
{"new":[{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16","scheduled_by_system":null}],"removed":[]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
{"new":[{"start":"2017-01-28","end":"2017-02-03"},{"start":"2017-02-04","end":"2017-02-10"},{"start":"2017-02-11","end":"2017-02-17"},{"start":"2017-02-18","end":"2017-02-24"},{"start":"2017-03-04","end":"2017-03-10"},{"start":"2017-03-11","end":"2017-03-17"},{"start":"2017-03-18","end":"2017-03-24"},{"start":"2017-09-02","end":"2017-09-08"},{"start":"2017-09-16","end":"2017-09-22"},{"start":"2017-09-23","end":"2017-09-29"},{"start":"2017-09-30","end":"2017-10-06"},{"start":"2017-10-07","end":"2017-10-13"},{"start":"2017-12-02","end":"2017-12-08"},{"start":"2017-12-09","end":"2017-12-15"},{"start":"2017-12-16","end":"2017-12-22"},{"start":"2017-12-23","end":"2017-12-29"},{"start":"2018-01-06","end":"2018-01-12"}],"removed":[{"start":"2017-02-04","end":"2017-02-10"},{"start":"2017-02-11","end":"2017-02-17"},{"start":"2017-02-18","end":"2017-02-24"},{"start":"2017-03-04","end":"2017-03-10"},{"start":"2017-03-11","end":"2017-03-17"},{"start":"2017-03-18","end":"2017-03-24"},{"start":"2017-01-28","end":"2017-02-03"},{"start":"2017-09-16","end":"2017-09-22"},{"start":"2017-09-02","end":"2017-09-08"},{"start":"2017-09-30","end":"2017-10-06"},{"start":"2017-10-07","end":"2017-10-13"},{"start":"2017-09-23","end":"2017-09-29"},{"start":"2017-12-16","end":"2017-12-22"},{"start":"2017-12-23","end":"2017-12-29"},{"start":"2018-01-06","end":"2018-01-12"},{"start":"2017-12-09","end":"2017-12-15"},{"start":"2017-12-02","end":"2017-12-08"},{"start":"2018-02-10","end":"2018-02-16"}]}|
```

and the regex:

```
a_regex = r'\"new\":{(.*?)}{2}|\"new\":\[(.*?)\]'
b_regex = r'\"removed\":{(.*?)}{2}|removed\":\[(.*?)\]'
date_regex = r'\"start\":\"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\"'
```

dfA.select('raw').show(2,False)

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|raw                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"new":[{"start":"2018-03-24","end":"2018-03-30","scheduled_by_system":null}],"removed":[]}|
|{"new":[{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16","scheduled_by_system":null}],"removed":[]}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

df.select('raw').printSchema()

```
root
 |-- raw: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: please share what you've tried, sample input and expected output too.

Comment: done, the expected output is obviously the populated list

Comment: what is the condition to get the X rows from A. Can you post with sample input and expected output?

Comment: also explain `For each row in A, depending on a field, create one or more rows of a new dataframe B`

Comment: hi ramesh, first of all, let me paste what i have right now so you see what i'm trying to do:

Comment: i've edited the question again :)

Comment: now put some sample input data or dataframe, explain the logic as you already have done in the question and finally put the expected dataframe. If you do that you are certain to get an answer not only from me but from others too.

Comment: You can just include the `raw` column from dfA. and what are `a_regex`, `date_regex` and `b_regex`?

Comment: everything is in the question now

Comment: dfA.raw is a stringType right? just do `dfA.select('raq').show(2, False)` and `dfA.select('raw').printSchema()` and copy paste them as well. we are very close now :)

Comment: i've added that info, it's kind of the same as the examples i put before

Comment: I have answered it below :) I hope the answer is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a `udf` function to return the `event_type` and `event_date` strings after you have selected the required `raw` column.

```
import re
def searchUdf(regex, dateRegex, x):
    list_return = []
    string = re.search(regex, x)
    if string:
        dates = re.findall(dateRegex, string.group())
        for date in dates:
            date_string = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            list_return.append(date_string)
    return list_return

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
udfFunctionCall = F.udf(searchUdf, T.ArrayType(T.DateType()))
```

The `udf` function would parse the raw column string with the *regex* and *dateRegex* passed as arguments and return *eventType* and *data_string* as `arrayType` column

You should be calling the `udf` function defined and `filter` out the empty rows and then *separate* the columns as `event_type` and `event_date` columns

```
df = df.select("raw")
adf = df.select(F.lit(1).alias("event_type"), udfFunctionCall(F.lit(a_regex), F.lit(date_regex), df.raw).alias("event_date"))\
    .filter(F.size(F.col("event_date")) > 0)

bdf = df.select(F.lit(2).alias("event_type"), udfFunctionCall(F.lit(a_regex), F.lit(date_regex), df.raw).alias("event_date")) \
    .filter(F.size(F.col("event_date")) > 0)
```

The *regex* used are provided in the question as

```
a_regex = r'\"new\":{(.*?)}{2}|\"new\":\[(.*?)\]'
b_regex = r'\"removed\":{(.*?)}{2}|removed\":\[(.*?)\]'
date_regex = r'\"start\":\"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\"'
```

Now that you have two `dataframes` for both `event_type`, final step is to *merge* them together

```
adf.unionAll(bdf)
```

And thats it. Your confusion is all solved.

With the following raw column

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|raw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"new":[],"removed":[{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16","scheduled_by_system":null}]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|{"new":[{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16","scheduled_by_system":null}],"removed":[]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|{"new":[{"start":"2017-01-28","end":"2017-02-03"},{"start":"2017-02-04","end":"2017-02-10"},{"start":"2017-02-11","end":"2017-02-17"},{"start":"2017-02-18","end":"2017-02-24"},{"start":"2017-03-04","end":"2017-03-10"},{"start":"2017-03-11","end":"2017-03-17"},{"start":"2017-03-18","end":"2017-03-24"},{"start":"2017-09-02","end":"2017-09-08"},{"start":"2017-09-16","end":"2017-09-22"},{"start":"2017-09-23","end":"2017-09-29"},{"start":"2017-09-30","end":"2017-10-06"},{"start":"2017-10-07","end":"2017-10-13"},{"start":"2017-12-02","end":"2017-12-08"},{"start":"2017-12-09","end":"2017-12-15"},{"start":"2017-12-16","end":"2017-12-22"},{"start":"2017-12-23","end":"2017-12-29"},{"start":"2018-01-06","end":"2018-01-12"}],"removed":[{"start":"2017-02-04","end":"2017-02-10"},{"start":"2017-02-11","end":"2017-02-17"},{"start":"2017-02-18","end":"2017-02-24"},{"start":"2017-03-04","end":"2017-03-10"},{"start":"2017-03-11","end":"2017-03-17"},{"start":"2017-03-18","end":"2017-03-24"},{"start":"2017-01-28","end":"2017-02-03"},{"start":"2017-09-16","end":"2017-09-22"},{"start":"2017-09-02","end":"2017-09-08"},{"start":"2017-09-30","end":"2017-10-06"},{"start":"2017-10-07","end":"2017-10-13"},{"start":"2017-09-23","end":"2017-09-29"},{"start":"2017-12-16","end":"2017-12-22"},{"start":"2017-12-23","end":"2017-12-29"},{"start":"2018-01-06","end":"2018-01-12"},{"start":"2017-12-09","end":"2017-12-15"},{"start":"2017-12-02","end":"2017-12-08"},{"start":"2018-02-10","end":"2018-02-16"}]}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You should be getting

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|event_type|event_date                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1         |[2018-03-10]                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|1         |[2017-01-28, 2017-02-04, 2017-02-11, 2017-02-18, 2017-03-04, 2017-03-11, 2017-03-18, 2017-09-02, 2017-09-16, 2017-09-23, 2017-09-30, 2017-10-07, 2017-12-02, 2017-12-09, 2017-12-16, 2017-12-23, 2018-01-06]|
|2         |[2018-03-10]                                                                                                                                                                                                |
|2         |[2017-01-28, 2017-02-04, 2017-02-11, 2017-02-18, 2017-03-04, 2017-03-11, 2017-03-18, 2017-09-02, 2017-09-16, 2017-09-23, 2017-09-30, 2017-10-07, 2017-12-02, 2017-12-09, 2017-12-16, 2017-12-23, 2018-01-06]|
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hey Ramesh, that looks very good... i'm going to try it with all the cases (new but not removed, removed but no new and a lot of news and a lot of removes) to see how it works, and i'll let you know (and accept the answer if everything goes well :) ) a lot of thanks for the huge help

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I'm sorry but it doesn't work u_u. For this input:
{"new":[],"removed":[{"start":"2018-02-24","end":"2018-03-02"},{"start":"2018-03-03","end":"2018-03-09"},{"start":"2018-03-10","end":"2018-03-16"},{"start":"2018-03-17","end":"2018-03-23"},{"start":"2018-03-24","end":"2018-03-30"}]}
it only gets the first one, as far as i know, **filter** will get the rows with at least one entry, but reviewing the code you sent, only gets the first one... am i missing something? why is not working? thanks!

Comment: can you explain by you saying `it only gets the first one` ?

Comment: because i only get a df with one row that has event_type = 2 and event_date=2018-02-24 (which is the first row)

Comment: I have updated my answer with input dataframe before the udf function, filter, select and union and output dataframe after applying all the functions. Please comment if the output is not what is required.

Comment: with that, you get from three input, four output dataframes, one for the first, one for the second, and two for the third, but the third has a lot of starts and ends, and we should be getting a row for each of them

Comment: I have updated the answer :) its more concise and I guess I got it correct this time. :)

Comment: hi Ramesh, with that solution the output is:
event_type - array of dates, what i need is a row for each date, so if for one event_type we have more than one date, have it in different rows, not in the same as an array :)

Comment: just use explode function on event_date and you should be fine

Comment: yes i was just doing that just now hahha, great, thanks a lot for the help Ramesh!

Comment: great feeling to have helped you :) and thanks for the acceptance and upvote :)

Comment: not just help but also taught me a couple of tricks for the future :)